# Poisson processes: traffic question

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Traffic follows a Poisson
process with rate 6 cars per minute. A deer runs out of the woods and
tries to cross the road. If there is a car passing in the next 5 seconds
then there will be a collision. (a) Find the probability of a collision.
(b) What is the chance of a collision if the deer only needs 2 seconds
to cross the road.

So the rate is 0.1 cars per second, and the expected number of cars in 5 seconds = 5*(6/60) = 0.5 = λ. I'm not really sure how to put this together to answer the problem.

Comment: If $\lambda = 0.5$ then what is $P(X=0)$? $P(X\not =0)$?

Comment: P(X=0)=e^(-0.5), so P(X≥1)=1-P(X=0) = 1-e^(-0.5) ? Would that be the answer for part a?

Comment: Does anyone know how to start part b?

Comment: Perhaps change $5$ seconds to $2$?

Answer (score 0):

If the average number of cars in $5$ seconds is $0.5$ then the probability of no cars during that time is
$$\frac{0.5^0 e^{-0.5}}{0!}.$$